# ValidationException: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

My cron syntax is

cron(25 8 10 2 4 2022)

And I wish to run the job exactly once on Thursday February 10 at 8:25 am. But getting the above error when trying to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule lambda event using following syntax:

```sh
# NOTE: This will execute on UTC mode only
cron(Minutes Hours Day-of-month Month Day-of-week Year)
```

So your cron expression should look like:

```sh
cron(25 08 10 02 ? 2022)
```

For more information, here is the [official AWS Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)